# Group and count observations per year from a dataset containing interval data

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data concerning the activity of a number of different writers, the data includes the `start.date` and `end.date` of their writing careers

```
library("tidyverse")
writing_period_data <- tribble(
  ~start.date, ~end.date, ~writer, ~topic,
  12, 18, "a", sample(letters[10:20],1),
  14, 20, "b", sample(letters[10:20],1),
  17, 22, "c", sample(letters[10:20],1),
  15, 30, "a", sample(letters[10:20],1)
)
```

I would like to ultimately create a joyplot of this data, which requires me to generate this data structure:

```
desired_output <- tribble(
  ~year, ~count, ~writer,
  12, 1, "a",
  13, 1, "a",
  14, 1, "a",
  14, 1, "b",
  15, 2, "a",
  15, 1, "b",
  16, 2, "a",
  16, 1, "b",
  17, 2, "a",
  17, 1, "b",
  17, 1, "c",
  18, 2, "a",
  18, 1, "b",
  18, 1, "c",
  19, 1, "a",
  19, 1, "b",
  19, 1, "c",
  20, 1, "a",
  20, 1, "b",
  20, 1, "c",
  21, 1, "a",
  21, 1, "c",
  22, 1, "a",
  22, 1, "c",
  23, 1, "a",
  24, 1, "a"
)
```

Which we can see from this chart demonstrates the distribution of writers across the time period of interest:

```
desired_output %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = count, fill = writer)) + geom_col()
```

[image]

How can I go about generating `desired_output` from `writing_period_data`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution from `tidyverse`. `dt` is the final output.

```
library(tidyverse)

dt <- writing_period_data %>%
  mutate(year = map2(start.date, end.date, `:`)) %>%
  unnest() %>%
  count(year, writer) %>%
  select(year, count = n, writer)
```

Comment: That's super powerful - I'm currently an absolute novice with `purrr`, thanks for this awesome example!